# iPhone see apps downloaded from different Apple ID

Tags: ios, applications, apple-id

On iOS 12 iPhone is there a way to see a list of apps downloaded from a different Apple ID (the one I’m not currently signed-in to). I would like to get all apps on one account so I don’t have to input passwords for several different Apple ID’s.

Answer (score 1):

No, in general, that would abuse the privacy of the other account.

The only exception is if all Apple ID were in family sharing and opted in to share app information. Then you can browse the other purchases from your account.

There also isn't a way on device to see which account purchased which apps if you happen to sequence several accounts to purchase on one device.